# Reading from file in C - Wrong output

Tags: c

I am writing a code to read from a file but it always prints wrong output.

The code is as follows:

```
int n;
struct threeNum num = { 0 };
FILE *fptr;

if ((fptr = fopen("input.txt", "rb")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error! opening file\n");

        // Program exits if the file pointer returns NULL.
        exit(1);
    }

for (n = 1; n < 5; ++n)
{
        fread(&num, sizeof(struct threeNum), 1, fptr);
        printf("n1: %d\tn2: %d\tn3: %d\n", num.n1, num.n2, num.n3);
}
fclose(fptr);
```

The struct is:

```
struct threeNum
{
    char n1, n2, n3;
};
```

And the .txt file is:

```
1 2 3
5 6 7
6 6 9
5 5 5
8 7 2
```

And I always get zeros printed.

Comment: You have not shown the `struct` definition but the use of `%d` specifier in `printf` suggests its members are `int`. These will not align with the data in the file which in any case is text, not binary values.

Answer (score 2):

`fread` reads binary objects, but your file is text. You need to read text and then parse that (such as with `fscanf`, or `fgets` followed by `sscanf`).

Comment: Can you send an example?

Comment: @user9128464 `int i1, i2, i3; fscanf(fptr, " %d %d %d", &i1, &i2, &i3);` but add check for return value (and possibly the range of values read, if they need to fit in `char`). In particular, do not read directly with `&num.n1` etc. unless you change their type to `int`.

Comment: Please clarify. Do you want to parse digits as characters or as integers?

Answer (score 0):

```
// As @Arkku said, use fgets to read each line and sscanf to parse it. 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
int num[15];
int totalRead, i = 0;
char dataToRead[50];
FILE *fp;

if ((fp = fopen("file.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error! opening file\n");
        // Program exits if the file pointer returns NULL.
        exit(1);
    }
// read the file
while (fgets(dataToRead, 50, fp) != NULL) {
    totalRead = sscanf(dataToRead, "%d%d%d", &num[i], &num[i+1], &num[i+2]);
    puts(dataToRead);
    i = i + 3;
}
// I used modulo so that after every 3rd element there is a newline
for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    printf("%d ", num[i]);
    if ((i+1) % 3 == 0)
        printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide some context to your answer so that it will help others to understand your approach, easily.